# How fill a loaded STL mesh ( NOT SIMPLE SHAPES LIKE CUBE ETC) with random particles and animate with this geometry bound in three.js

Tags: three.js, points

**How I can fill a loaded STL mesh ( like suzane NOT SIMPLE SHAPES LIKE CUBE etc) with random particles and animate it inside this geometry bounds with three.js ?**

I see many examples but all of it for simple shapes with geometrical bounds like cube or sphere with limit by coordinates around center

```
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=points#webgl_custom_attributes_points3
```

TNX

Comment: To start, see: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_dynamic.html.

Comment: This is not very easy to do. A mesh can have many triangles that you need to check, and just brute-forcing it may not work. Cubes and spheres are simple to evaluate mathematically hence you see those shapes being used for something like this.

Comment: yes yes,  about https://threejs.org/examples/?q=points#webgl_points_dynamic it's another soluion when using vertexes of geometru of mesh like points material..  I already do it , but how  I can fill volume of this meshes?  I need algotithm to detect corrdinates incuded in the mesh volume ((

Comment: Maybe this thread will give you some ideas: https://answers.unity.com/questions/611947/am-i-inside-a-volume-without-colliders.html

Comment: is too complex solution to not simlple shapes.

Comment: What do U think about my one:  1. devide my mesh through z axis ( slice it) to 2d shapes with common z coordinate and then we can use this for testing points coordinates ,  but how i can slice my mesh and get this arrays?

Comment: Such questions better to ask on the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/), as they involve opinionated comments and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concept, using a ray, that counts intersections of the ray with faces of a mesh, and if the number is odd, it means that the point is inside of the mesh:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/LgabWZ)

```
  function fillWithPoints(geometry, count) {

    var ray = new THREE.Ray()

    var size = new THREE.Vector3();
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    let bbox = geometry.boundingBox;

    let points = [];

    var dir = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      let p = setRandomVector(bbox.min, bbox.max);
      points.push(p);
    }

    function setRandomVector(min, max){
      let v = new THREE.Vector3(
        THREE.Math.randFloat(min.x, max.x),
        THREE.Math.randFloat(min.y, max.y),
        THREE.Math.randFloat(min.z, max.z)
      );
      if (!isInside(v)){return setRandomVector(min, max);}
      return v;
    }

    function isInside(v){

      ray.set(v, dir);
      let counter = 0;

      let pos = geometry.attributes.position;
      let faces = pos.count / 3;
      let vA = new THREE.Vector3(), vB = new THREE.Vector3(), vC = new THREE.Vector3();

      for(let i = 0; i < faces; i++){
        vA.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i * 3 + 0);
        vB.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i * 3 + 1);
        vC.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i * 3 + 2);
        if (ray.intersectTriangle(vA, vB, vC)) counter++;
      }

      return counter % 2 == 1;
    }

    return new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
  }
```

Comment: ThankYou !!  can't replay there.. reached limit of replays. 
  Looking good and work fine  , today try to do movement of point for looking like create mesh from one point and make animation back

Comment: You're welcome :) Mark the answer as accepted, please, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The concepts from the previous answer is very good, but it has some performance limitations:

- the whole geometry is tested with every ray
- the recursion on points outside can lead to stack overflow

Moreover, it's incompatible with indexed geometry.

It can be improved by creating a spatial hashmap storing the geometry triangles and limiting the intersection test to only some part of the mesh.

[Demonstration](https://github.com/heroncendre/Volpar)

[image]